# Semantic Errors in Android NDK under Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, ubuntu, android-ndk

I read about similar issues in other forums but their solutions didn't work for me.

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:

When I run my Android project in Eclipse with NDK I encounter the following problem.

-Compilation works fine,  App launches

-UNTIL I open a file inside the project.

-Then tons of "semantic errors" occur

-Then I cannot compile it anymore (even though I didnt modify any line of code)

EXAMPLE ERRORS:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Function 'abs' could not be resolved    Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 355    Semantic Error
Function 'acos' could not be resolved   Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 467    Semantic Error
Function 'acos' could not be resolved   Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 535    Semantic Error
Function 'atan2' could not be resolved  Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 298    Semantic Error
Function 'atan2' could not be resolved  Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 335    Semantic Error
Function 'atan2' could not be resolved  Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 466    Semantic Error
Function 'atan2' could not be resolved  Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 534    Semantic Error
Function 'infinity' could not be resolved   Dataset.cpp /testproject/jni/Data   line 105    Semantic Error
```

Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you delete the errors from Eclipse then try launching?

Comment: Yes you can but it's so annoying to do it every minute :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the `Scanner Configuration Builder` in builders list in project properties